# blackberry: onkeyup doesn't catch BACKSPACE

Tags: blackberry, onkeyup, blackberry-webworks

i need to get value of a INPUT of type TEXT in real time. So i assigned to onkeyup of the INPUT to my function, that evaluates the new value.

It works fine on BB (i use 9780/OS6 for tests) except, that BACKSPACE-Key doesn't fire the event.

[Here](http://pastehtml.com/view/au960a9ac.html) there's an example of code.

may be you have an idea, how to solve it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Daniel

Comment: How about using both keyup and keydown?

Comment: @Aen Tan: do you have an example? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In BB Backspace doesn't fire any of the key events (keydown/keypress/keyup).  Did you solve this?